# SharePoint2013 search exception using CSOM

Tags: search-results, client-object-model

I have created Bing result source and have attached to SharePoint search. When I go to the search site and perform search it's returning results, but when I tried to access the results using csom it's throwing error.

Code I executed:

```
        using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("searchsite"))
        {
            KeywordQuery keywordQuery = new KeywordQuery(clientContext);
            keywordQuery.QueryText = "SharePoint";
            SearchExecutor searchExecutor = new SearchExecutor(clientContext);
            ClientResult<ResultTableCollection> results = searchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(keywordQuery);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            ResultTable result = results.Value[0];
```

Here is the error message :

> Additional information: Search has encountered a problem that prevents
>   results from being returned.  If the issue persists, please contact
>   your administrator.

Log file information :

> 04/10/2014 14:34:29.29    w3wp.exe (0x421C)0x1228 SharePoint Server
>   Search Query afpkb Unexpected Getting results failed:
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.InternalQueryErrorException:
>   Search has encountered a problem that prevents results from being
>   returned.  If the issue persists, please contact your administrator.
>   at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.ThrowGenericQueryException(String
>   operationName)     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.DoSpLoadBalancedUriWsOp[T](WebServiceBackedOperation`1
>   webServiceCall, Int32 timeoutInMilliseconds, Int32
>   wcfTimeoutInMilliseconds, String operationName)     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.DoWebServiceBackedOperation[T](String
>   operationName, Int32 timeoutInMilliseconds, Int32
>   wcfTimeoutInMilliseconds,
>   WebServic...  e6d0859c-c370-909e-7a5e-a9ce3ab96222 04/10/2014
>   14:34:29.29*  w3wp.exe (0x421C)
>
>     0x1228  SharePoint Server Search        Query
>
>     afpkb   Unexpected  ...eBackedOperation`1 webServiceCall)     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.Execute(QueryProperties
>   properties)     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Query.ExecuteQuery()     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.ExecuteQueryInternal(Query
>   query)     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(Query
>   query)     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.ExecuteQueries(Dictionary`2
>   queries, Boolean handleExceptions)     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.ScriptApplicationManager.GetSyncResult(String
>   queryGroupName)     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.DataProviderScriptWebPart.GetInitialResult()   e6d0859c-c370-909e-7a5e-a9ce3ab96222

What goes wrong?